# Powershell - Doing a SaveAs with an Excel file I receive a Cannot access read-only document error

Tags: excel, powershell

Good Morning,
I am new to Power Shell and I cobbled together a script to open, copy , and paste data from one excel sheet to another on a network drive. I can run it once and it works , but if I try to run it again I get the "Cannot access read-only document". I assume I am not opening and closing the excel application and workbooks properly. Any advice is appreciated.

```
#Start Excel
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
#$excel.Visible = $true
#$excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
$wb1= $excel.workbooks.open($file1)
$wb2 = $excel.workbooks.open($file2)
$ws1 = $wb1.WorkSheets.item(1)
$ws1exemptions = $wb1.WorkSheets.item(4)
$ws1totals = $wb1.WorkSheets.item(3)
$ws2 = $wb2.Worksheets.item(1)
$ws1.activate()
#Get number of rows to delete on Sheet1
$mydelrowcount = $ws1.UsedRange.rows.count
#Assign variable to make range A2:H(number of rows) $range = $mysheet.range("A2:H" + $myrowcount)
$mydelrange = "A2:H" + $mydelrowcount
#Select the rows
$deleteme = $ws1.range("A2:H" + $mydelrange)
#Delete rows fromm $file1!Sheet1
$deleteme.clear()
#Go to Sheet 1 of APOTHER (file2)
$ws2.activate()
#Get number of rows to copy from Sheet1
$mynewrowcount = $ws2.UsedRange.rows.count
#Assign variable to make range A2:H(number of rows) 
$mynewrange = "A2:H" + $mynewrowcount
#Select the rows
$selectme = $ws2.range("A2:H" + $mynewrowcount)
#Copy the rows
$selectme.Copy()
#Go to Sheet1 of TestFiletoSend (file1)
$ws1.activate()
#Select the same number of rows in Sheet1 (variable in $mynewrange)
$ws1.Range($mynewrange).Select()
#Paste the rows into A2:H(number of rows)
$ws1.Paste()
$ws1.Cells.Range("A1").Select()
$ws1totals.activate()
$wb1.SaveAs($file1)#                                                                                                
$wb1.Close()
$wb2.Close()
$excel.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel)
# no $ needed on variable name in Remove-Variable call
Remove-Variable excel
```

Comment: how soon after are you trying to open it? You could leave it open setting `.Visible` to `$true`.

Comment: Hi Abraham, when I set visibility to true, It looks like the script is opening the file twice.

Comment: You can make sure Excel doesn't open the second workbook in read-only mode by checking `$wb1.ReadOnly` before saving/continuing

Comment: Thank you!
I could not get back to this until late this afternoon. 
Abraham - Setting the visibility to true enabled me to see that the file was opening a second time by a subsequent command in another script. 
Cpt.Whale - I also set the 2nd work sheet to activate and close prior to the saving of the 1st worksheet which helped me troubleshoot the issue (executing the script line by line.)